# How to play mp4 video in android

Tags: android, video, video-streaming, mp4

I want to play mp4 video from server in android.
[Video URL](http://victoryfireworks.com.c1.previewmysite.com/images/stories/movies12/Night_Rage.mp4)

I tried with using video view but there is blank screen appear.
I also tried with Intent.Action view but it show message "Cant play video".

Is there any other way to do this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the video play with other players, such as MX Player?